# Functional programming in Groovy; Apart from curry method:?

Tags: groovy

Last night i have read about the `curry()` method in Groovy and i felt the feeling of functional programming, with the use of this `curry()` method.

As a novice in Groovy language, are there any methods in Groovy which provides functional programming capabilities as `curry()` method does?

It will be good, if those methods are been explained with an simple example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Functional+Programming+with+Groovy

Comment: @virtualeyes That page was last edited in 2008. I hope some newer answers could be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also [Closure composition](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/237001)

```
def plus2  = { it + 2 }
def times3 = { it * 3 }

def composed1 = plus2 << times3
assert composed1(3) == 11
```

And you can use the Method Reference operator `&` to get a reference to a class method, which you can then use with currying or composition.

ie:

```
def parseIntRef = Integer.&parseInt

def binaryParse = parseIntRef.rcurry( 2 )
def hexParse    = parseIntRef.rcurry( 16 )

assert binaryParse( '110' ) == 6
assert hexParse(    '0A'  ) == 10
```

---

There are 3 forms of `curry` for closures;

1. The [basic `curry` method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/lang/Closure.html#curry%28java.lang.Object%29) which starts currying the parameters of a Closure from the left most parameter
2. Then there is [the `rcurry` method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/lang/Closure.html#rcurry%28java.lang.Object%29), which starts currying the parameters from the right
3. And finally, [there is `ncurry`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/lang/Closure.html#ncurry%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) which starts at the index specified by you.

All 3 of those curry methods are well described in the documentation if you follow the links :-)

Comment: in the second example what is `rcurry`?

Comment: i guess its `curry` and you have misspelled it. And by the way when i run this code I'm getting an error..as `No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.parseInt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String) values: [2, 110]`

Comment: @ant added description of the 3 possible curry methods...  I have to use `rcurry` in my example as the `radix` parameter is the rightmost parameter in the static `Integer.parseInt` method.  I could also have used `def binaryParse = parseIntRef.ncurry( 1, 2 )` to set the second parameter to `2`, but this is (imho) less pretty

Comment: @ant No, I did not misspell it, i meant `rcurry`.  The error you are seeing is because you are trying to use `curry` to set the leftmost parameter (a String) with an integer value

Comment: @tim: yes i got what i did wrong.... But is this `rcurry` method available in Groovy 1.7?  Because I'm getting an error still if i use `rcurry`

Comment: @tim:I'm getting the output in the groovyConsole site.. Guess this `rcurry` method is not in my Groovy version.. Thanks sir once again :)

Comment: @ant `rcurry` was introduced in Groovy 1.7.2 afaik

Comment: @tim: i have been using groovy 1.7.0 :( will update to Groovy 1.8 soon :)